# byte-buddy defining an enum with abstract methods

Tags: byte-buddy

I was wondering if there is a way to create an enum like this with byte-buddy:

```
public enum EnumWithAbstractMethods {
    A {
        @Override
        String greet() {
            return "hello A";
        }
    },
    B {
        @Override
        String greet() {
            return "hello B";
        }
    },
    C {
        @Override
        String greet() {
            return "hello C";
        }
    };

    abstract String greet();
}
```

I have played with the byte-buddy APIs for creating enum and I found no way that I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally not create subclasses but use `DynamicType.Builder::makeEnumeration` and implement the method and determine the outcome dynamically from it. For example, you could use a `MethodDelegation` to intercept to a dispatcher which takes a parameter of `@This Enum<?>`. Then switch on the ordinal and return the value you consider.

Alternatively, you can of course create four classes and implement the enum semantics manually.

Comment: Well yes, I can fake this enum but I would rather not since then in the program I am writing I need to add a complete separate logic for this case. Is there any chance that this case will be supported in the new versions of byte-buddy ?